# set attribute value of input element with script tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the value on an input element like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="loginButton" value="<script>document.write(language['login'])</script>"/>
```

but i can't get it to work. Is it not possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible, but not _that_ way. The `value` is pure text, you can not put script code in there and expect that to get executed.

Comment: Set this value by getting element through document.getElementById in javascript

Comment: Ok, of course i knew about these different approaches but was just wondering.  I was thinking of some kind of escape  that would make it possible but it can't be done like that. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript, you can attribute a value to the property `value` by using `setAttribute` function.

Here is a possible solution :

```
var button = document.getElementById("#loginButton"); //Select your button element
button.setAttribute("value","Your value to set"); //Set value attribute to your element
```

Good luck !